# Tooltip and Popover are not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tooltip, popover

I have a problem with my tooltips and popovers. I've just imported jquery before bootstrap,like that:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.6', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'personal', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/personal.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_register_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', false, '3.3.1', true );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.6', true);
```

And I've just created my two shortcodes with the tooltip and popover. And in my js file I have this calls:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
```

But the console browser shows me that:

> jquery.js?ver=3.3.1:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a
>   function

If someone knows help me, please ! Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if bootstrap JS was correctly loaded? You could check that in the console in the HTML

Comment: Also have you checked that your JS file is after the loading of the bootstrap and jquery? You could also put those two lines like that in the console, if you do that and it works, you have isolated the case that both bootstrap and jquery are loading correctly, and also that the error lies in how you are calling the two lines of tooltip() and popover().

Comment: Yes I checked and my js file is loaded after bootstrap and jquery. And when I look my code in the browser, yes these two are loaded. So the error continue...

Comment: @Leo I've solved it. The problem was the jQuery version. So Thanks so much for your help !